# Using Overmind DevTools with React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I cannot connect to Overmind Devtools using React Native. I use Expo and connect to it with an iPad on LAN.

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/an1cux/anyone_tried_using_react_native_with_overmind/) post, it should be possible to connect to Overmind Devtools from anywhere since it is an Electron app, but I couldn't figure out how.

On my iPad I get this message:

```
OVERMIND DEVTOOLS: Not able to connect. You are trying to connect to "localhost:3031", but there was no devtool there. Try the following:
   - Make sure you are running the latest version of the devtools, using "npx overmind-devtools@latest" or install latest extension for VSCode
   - Close the current tab and open a new one
   - Make sure the correct port is configured in the devtools
```

Which makes sense, since on the iPad's localhost there is definitely no Overmind Devtools running, but I do not know how to connect it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass configuration to `createOvermind` and specify host and port like so:

```js
const overmind = createOvermind(config, { devtools: 'http://0.0.0.0:3031' })
```

[relevant spot in docs](https://overmindjs.org/api/createOvermind?view=react&typescript=true)

Comment: Thanks, that led me to the right direction, with the help of Christian Alfoni (creator of Overmind), we figured it out. I needed to add the LOCAL IP address of my laptop that was running the devTools, but WITHOUT the http:// part. Now it works.

Comment: @SimonSzalai Nice! You guys happen to figure out why that was the case?